# cx_Oracle connect - connection string with load balancing

Tags: cx-oracle

I have connection string in format

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (LOAD_BALANCE=ON) 
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = aaa)(PORT = 1531))
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = bbb)(PORT = 1526))
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = ccc)(PORT = 1526))
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = ddd)(PORT = 1526))
 (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=a.b.org))
)
```

How can I use cx_Oracle connect

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect( .... )
```

using connection string in above specified format  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite simple. You can do the following:

```
dsn = """(DESCRIPTION = (LOAD_BALANCE=ON) 
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = aaa)(PORT = 1531))
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = bbb)(PORT = 1526))
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = ccc)(PORT = 1526))
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = ddd)(PORT = 1526))
 (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=a.b.org))
)

"""
cx_Oracle.connect("user", "password", dsn)
```

Effectively, any connect string that you can find in a tnsnames.ora file you can also pass directly as the dsn parameter to cx_Oracle.connect.